# ISODate in --queryFile

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodump

I use the below mongodump code to dump records based on a date, in an `.sh` file:

```
$MONGODUMP_PATH -h $MONGO_HOST:$MONGO_PORT 
-d $MONGO_DATABASE  -c $MONGO_COLLECTION 
--queryFile subset.json
```

`subset.json`:

```
{ "TheDate": { "$gte": new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1)) } }
```

That does not work, and produces an error:

```
Failed: error parsing query as json: invalid character '.' after constructor argument
```

But if I change `subset.json` to include a static date value, it works:

```
{ "TheDate": { "$gte": ISODate("2016-06-14T07:12:23.051Z") } }
```

Where `ISODate("2016-06-14T07:12:23.051Z")` equals `new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 1))` as previously.

But I would need a dynamic value for date, as in the first case. 
Have been looking for a solution online but cant find any...

Any ideas?
Best Regards

Comment: I am also facing same issue, How do i solve this problem.

Comment: Hi, try this link: https://sheharyar.me/blog/regular-mongo-backups-using-cron/, dumps the whole db with cron.

Comment: how to resolve the below issue.

mongodump --db test --collection data --query '{"created_at":{"$gte":new Date(ISODate().getTime()-1000*60*15)}}' --username abcd --password abc@123 --authenticationDatabase admin -o "mongodump_15mins_data"


ERROR:

2016-08-29T12:17:46.802+0000    Failed: error parsing query as json: invalid character '.' after constructor argument

when i run mongodump query above error i got it.

Comment: Did not find solution for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope it working for me !!!**

The problem is your query is not valid JSON as it contains JS expressions to be evaluated (your calculations with the date).

In addition I did (quick & dirty) something similar with **node**, i.e. created a file **query.js** with this content which essentially creates your query JSON and writes it to the console

**var oid = Math.floor(new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000";**

**console.log('{ "_id": { "$gte": new ObjectId("' + oid + '") } }');**

so that you now can use it in your shell like so

**mongoexport ... --query "$(node query.js)" ...**

Please refer below link,

[Find 15 mins data with ObjectID field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205107/find-15-mins-data-with-objectid-field)