# Find 15 mins data with ObjectID field

Tags: mongodb

I am finding **latest 15 minutes** data with **ObjectID**.

**Find Query:**

```
db.data.find({ 
    _id: { 
        $gte: new ObjectId(
            Math.floor(new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 15) / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000"
        ) 
    } 
})
```

**Output**:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57c3ef6837ff7057a2ad3cca"), "User" : "Karthick", age: 26 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("57c3ef6837ff7057a2ad3cce"), "User" : "Raja", age: 29 }
```

But, I am trying to take the data dump,

```
mongodump --query '{ _id: { $gte: new ObjectId(Math.floor(new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 15) / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000") } }' --db test --collection data --username abcdef --password abc@123 --authenticationDatabase admin -o "mongodump"
```

**Error**

```
Failed: error parsing query as json: invalid character 't' in literal MaxKey (expecting 'x')
```

I am getting the above error. How do I solve this issue or how do I put 15 minutes data dump in cronjob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your query is not valid JSON as it contains JS expressions to be evaluated (your calculations with the date).
So you basically have to make a script or do some shell acrobatics which generates the query JSON prior passing it to `mongoexport`

You may find [this](http://www.ultrabug.fr/tag/mongoexport/) link useful which does exactly that with python

In addition I did (quick & dirty) something similar with node, i.e. created a file **query.js** with this content which essentially creates your query JSON and writes it to the console

```
var oid = Math.floor(new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 15) / 1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000";
console.log('{ "_id": { "$gte": new ObjectId("' + oid + '") } }');
```

so that you now can use it in your shell like so

```
mongoexport ... --query "$(node query.js)" ...
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks it's helping but i am getting all documents in output. inside query functions not working properly. Please help.